# Can download file on Sharepoint Online with user have View only permission level?

Tags: document-library

Today, I granted user01 have **View Only** Permission level.

User01 go to Document of SharePoint Online and perform to download existed file.

I can download file successfully.

But a month ago, same case user01 can't download file (Download menu is not displayed on Context menu) - Same as definition in this topic. [Difference b/w Read and View Only](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60257/difference-b-w-read-and-view-only)

Answer (score 1):

Users with view only permission level can indeed download documents. If you experienced any problems before it might have been caused by a temporary error.